# Javascript function returns undefined when using switch

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function stRequest(type){
  switch(type){
    case "favourites":
      $.getJSON("js/favourites.json")
      .done(function(data) {
        var message = "";
        $.each(data.favourites, function(){
          message += "<a href=\"#\" class=\"favourite-user\">" + this + "</a>";
        });
        return message;
      });
      break;
  }
}
```

When run using something like `console.log(stRequest("favourites"));` it always returns undefined. In short, what's the problem with my function?

Comment: Always remember that the **a** in _ajax_ (i.e. what's done with `getJSON`) stands for _asynchnonous_

Answer (score 4):

You're returning from the inner function.

You'd need to return from the outer function.

You need to pass a callback to be called inside of `done()` or use a promise. You could then resolve the callback with `message` as the argument.

Answer (score 1):

A promise is definitely the way to go.  Check out [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/).

```
function stRequest(type){
   var deferred = Q.defer();
   switch(type){
    case "favourites":
      $.getJSON("js/favourites.json")
      .done(function(data) {
        var message = "";
        $.each(data.favourites, function(){
          message += "<a href=\"#\" class=\"favourite-user\">" + this + "</a>";
        });
        deferred.resolve(message);
      });
      break;
  }
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

You would then call your function like so:

```
stRequest('favourites').then(function(message){
  alert(message);
});
```

Comment: Would it be possible to do the same thing with `$.Deferred();` as I am already using jQuery and am hesitant to add another script if unneeded?

Comment: @BenedictLewis https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/Coming-from-jQuery

Comment: @BenedictLewis I haven't used jQuery's version but looks pretty similar. http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/